# I want to return values from the subroutine (function) that GNU Parallel called in Bash

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

```
test() {
    return $1
}

export -f test
seq 1 5 | parallel test {} | echo
```

So I would like to see 1 2 3 4 5. Note, this is a simple case I'm aware that you can do this in many ways. However, I need to grab the result of the return in test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_test() { echo $1; }
export -f my_test
seq 1 5 | parallel my_test {} | parallel -Xj1 echo
```

`test` is a UNIX command, so to avoid confusion call your function something else.

If it really is the exit value you are interested in:

```
my_test() { return $1; }
export -f my_test
seq 1 5 | parallel 'my_test {};echo $?' | parallel -Xj1 echo
```

To learn more:

- Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1
- Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
  will love you for it.